# Stop site from directing to m.site.com

Tags: .htaccess, mobile

I just migrated my site to the godaddy cpanel hosting and am having a problem. When a user on a mobile device visits my site (www.site.com) they are being redirected to m.site.com - which I do not have nor want to have. How can I stop this using htaccess?

Comment: Are you sure there isn’t a .htaccess somewhere that is causing this that you could just remove? (Also are you sure there isn’t a configuration option to turn it off somewhere)?

Comment: I looked for an htaccess and could not find one. Spoke to the godaddy csr and was told it would be in my html_public folder but not there. Also check on the cpanel under the redirects rules and nothing there. Of course, the godaddy customer service / technical service is sometimes a hit or miss - so there may an htaccces file somewhere but the rep I spoke to had no clue what he was doing.

Comment: Have you looked above the html_public folder? It’ll only have an effect if it’s somewhere above

Answer (score -1):

Try Below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.m.domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For Https remove last line and add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This will most likely end up in a redirect loop if there’s some GoDaddy redirect rule somewhere else. And will it not cause a 301 redirect on *every* URL you enter?

Comment: Tried the above but did not work. Forgot to mention the site is also a https site. I changed the last line to https and then was not able to access the site from anywhere. was receiving a message on browser stating the site was not secure and would not allow me to continue.